# Регулярные выражения возвращают true/false

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, re, bool

Я хочу, чтоб программа возвращала не только "True", но и "False"( при некорректном вводе емэйла). Мне хотелось это сделать через регулярные выражение (хотя мы их ещё не проходили и у меня о них не очень хорошие представления). Я нашла в интернете вот такой код:

```
import re
welcome = "hi"
text = "abcdefghijkl"
print(bool(re.search(welcome, text)))
```

Захотела адаптировать для своей ситуации, но он перестал работать. Почему?!

```
import re
symbols = ("", "@", ".@")
email = str(input())
print(bool(re.search(symbols, email)))
```

Comment: Полагаю, что он перестал работать, потому что функция `re.search()` ожидает первым аргументом не кортеж `("", "@", ".@")`, а строку.

Comment: @Extend Вот чёрт((( А если я сделаю из кортежа строку с помощью join, то тогда все ведь потеряет смысл?!(((

Comment: @ВикаМельникова  - "все ведь потеряет смысл?!"

- А в чём смысл? Вы что хотите сделать? Найти символ '@' ?

Comment: прежде чем адаптировать код для свой ситуации нужно разобраться с тем, что этот код делает. Этот код (в общих словах) ищет **строку** welcome в строке text и потом сообщает, нашел ли. А адаптации вы строку заменили на кортеж, больше ничего не меняя. Что теперь должен делать код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял смысл, то требуется написать скрипт, который будет фильтровать некорректные варианты email. Итак, начнем с того, что сформируем  [регулярное выражение](https://tproger.ru/articles/regexp-for-beginners/), и присвоим его переменной `reg`:

```
reg = r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+$'
```

Следующим шагом создадим переменную, которая будет хранить данные, вводимые с клавиатуры (наш email адрес):

```
email = str(input())
```

Далее выводим в консоль результат проверки `email` используя `re.search()`:

```
print(bool(re.search(reg, email)))
```

Прошу обратить внимание на аргументы, которые принимает функция. Первый аргумент - это наше регулярное выражение, а второй - данные с клавиатуры.

Comment: Wow!!! Круто, спасибо, что так все хорошо объяснили!!! Я очень-очень благодарна)))))

Comment: @ВикаМельникова Рад, что помог :)